# Excel VBA copy row before deleting it

Tags: excel, vba

I need to create something like log for changes in Excel Worksheet.

For example, I have this list:
1. a b c
2. d e f
3. h i j

When I delete second row, I need its data to be copied to other worksheet, so my first list would look like:
1. a b c
3. h i j

And the second one:
2. d e f

Now I'm using this code:

```
Private usedRowsCount As Long

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
  usedRowsCount = Target.Worksheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count 
End Sub

Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  If usedRowsCount < Target.Worksheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count Then
    Debug.Print "Row Added: ", Target.Address
  ElseIf usedRowsCount > Target.Worksheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count Then
   Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:L2").Value = Target.Value ' here it inserts values of shifted up row. I need to get values of deleted row(s)
    Debug.Print "Row deleted: ", Target.Address
  End If
End Sub
```

But its copies not the deleted row data, but data of row below deleted one.
Example list:
1. a b c
3. h i j

Copied row data in the Sheet1:
3. h i j ----  not "2. d e f" as expected.

Any suggestions?

Thank you!

Comment: It can't copy cells if they no longer exist. You need to capture the contents of the deleted cells before they are deleted. I'm not even sure this is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this works for you, can't guarantee it will cover all cases.

You'll probably have to adjust for your precise set up.

```
Private usedRowsCount As Long, v As Variant

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
  usedRowsCount = Target.Worksheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
  v = Selection.Resize(, 3).Value 'columns A-C of selected row
End Sub

Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  If usedRowsCount < Target.Worksheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count Then
    Debug.Print "Row Added: ", Target.Address
  ElseIf usedRowsCount > Target.Worksheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count Then
   Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A2").Resize(, 3).Value = v
    Debug.Print "Row deleted: ", Target.Address
  End If
End Sub
```